# Run keyup function after delay

Tags: javascript

I have a function that I'd like to run on keyup after X seconds, at the minute its running on every keyup. I can;t quite figure out what I'm doing wrong so any advice would be helpful, thanks.

```
<input type="text" name="endLocation" id="endLocation" class="markerLoc" onkeyup="keyup()" />

var timer;
function keyup(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer=setTimeout(CalculateRoutes(),4000);
}
```

Comment: try `timer=setTimeout(function() { CalculateRoutes(); }, 4000);`

Comment: `CalculateRoutes()` runs the function immediately. Lose the parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoking `CalculateRoutes` right away and giving that result to `setTimeout`.

```
var timer;
function keyup(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer=setTimeout(CalculateRoutes,4000);
                                    ^ no parens
}
```

Comment: Ahh I didn't realise that with the parenthesis the function would run immediately, thanks!